# Traffic Signal Program C Basic

Tags: c

I have made a small basic traffic light program. It is not giving the output I'm expecting. I want it to print all five cases with change over time but instead in the second if else case, it prints "Red light   Red lightght" instead of "Red Light   Red Light" and starts to blink. Same is for 5th if else. What seems to be the problem?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    time_t strt, t;
    long difference = 0;
    int a, progrun;
    char start;
    printf("Press 1 to turn on the Traffic Light\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &progrun);
    if (progrun == 1)
    {
        strt = time(NULL);
        printf("East-West Signal   North-East Signal\n");
        while (difference < 15)
        {
            t = time(NULL);
            difference = t - strt;
            int light(difference);
            if (difference <= 3)
            {
                printf("Red Light   Green Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
            else if (difference > 3 && difference <= 6)
            {
                printf("Red Light   Yellow Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
            else if (difference > 5 && difference <= 8)
            {
                printf("Red Light   Red Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
            else if (difference > 8 && difference <= 10)
            {
                printf("Yellow Light   Red Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
            else if (difference > 10 && difference <= 12)
            {
                printf("Green Light   Red Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
            else if (difference > 12 && difference <= 14)
            {
                printf("Yellow Light   Yellow Light\r");
                fflush stdout;
            }
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Kindly, explain a little more. @OldProgrammer

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: `else if (difference > 5 && difference <= 8)` should be `else if (difference > 6 && difference <= 8)`  change it 5 to 6

Comment: I did that. Problem is still persisting. @Himanshu

Comment: `fflush stdout;` is a syntax error.

Comment: fflush stdout taken out. Plus I put more spaces in the cases where there was some problem. It's solved now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carriage return simply moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Then when you print, it overwrites characters, but it doesn't necessarily overwrite the entire line.

That means that the easiest fix is to add some spaces to the end of your print line.

```
printf("Red Light   Red Light   \r");
```